# Detect a paste event in a react-native text input

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to paste into a react native input, but do something based on the pasted content (i.e. if the pasted content is a link, style it accordingly). However, in order to do this I need to know when something has been pasted into the text input. I am not sure how to listen for a paste event. The Clipboard does not really help here because all it does it set/get content, not tell me if some arbitrary content has been pasted.

Comment: why don't you listen for a change event?

Comment: I listen for onChangeText, but that doesn't really help.

Comment: Why not listen for `paste`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Comment: There is no access to that clipboard in react-native, the one provided is an abstraction over the native ios clipboard.

Answer (score 10):

For people who come across this post from Google, and found no luck like me, fortunately, I found the solution although **not ideal** because it use `onChangeText` event.

The idea is simple, every time the text is changed, I will compare it with content from the clipboard. That's it.

**The minimal sample code**

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  handleOnPaste = (content) => {
    alert('paste detected! content: '.concat(content));
  }

  handleOnChangeText = async (content) => {
    if (content === '') return;
    const copiedContent = await Clipboard.getString();
    
    if (copiedContent === '') return;
    const isPasted = content.includes(copiedContent);
    if (isPasted) this.handleOnPaste(content);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder={'fill something'} 
          style={styles.input} 
          onChangeText={this.handleOnChangeText} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/@putuyoga/textinput-paste-event-listener), enjoy!

[image]

Comment: The code you have alerts every time the value of the text-input changes. It does **NOT** detect paste events.

Comment: @Rubek Joshi Yes, unfortunately, this is a dirty workaround because there is no native event to detect paste. But it won't alert every time like you said, only when the content clipboard is the same. I will update the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Pretty nice idea for very basic use, but I suspect this will backfire with new APIs detecting app clipboard reads. Apple now wants to inform the user every time your app reads the clipboard. Your users will probably become paranoid leave the review: "Why is this spyware app checking my clipboard the moment I try do anything?"

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been quite a while but I just came across this issue and found out the solution so wanted to share with the community.

Simply instead of using **onChangeText** prop of the TextInput component we can use the **onChange** prop. It works same as the former one, but in addition it also detect the paste event in the input field, which was our issue.

Talk is cheap. Show me the code. Here it is:

```
<TextInput
    style=styles.textInputView
    placeholder={'Enter Search Query...'}
    placeholderTextColor="#909AB9"
    value={this.state.searchQuery}
    // onChangeText={(text) => this.searchData(text)}
    onChange={({ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }) => this.searchData(text)}
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoCapitalize={'none'} />
```

All that is needed is your prayers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can keep 2 copies of the input in state, with 1 copy being the previous state of the input and the other being the state of the current input. Example being

```
Actual input: asd
this.state={copy_one: "as", copy_two: "asd"}

Actual input: asdgoogle.com
this.state={copy_one: "asd", copy_two: "asdgoogle.com"}
```

You can update them by doing

```
this.setState({copy_one: this.state.copy_two, copy_two: currentValue})
```

on every trigger of the onChange prop. If you're specifically looking for the changes, a quick and dirty hack to get only the difference would be do delete the original string via replacement

```
difference = this.state.copy_two.replace(this.state.copy_one, "")
```

then you can use regex to see if it's a link and stylize it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To detect a past event, in react-native, my solution works base on the app state.
so if an app is in the background that means the app is inactive  ***(user maybe is copying)*** else it will be the inactive mode ***(here we can check if the user make a copy action or not)***.
Please add this clipboard module first [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/clipboard)

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard';
import { View Text, TextInput} from "react-native"
export default const ScreenToPastIn = () => { 

const [pastContent,setPastContent] = useState('')

 useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    return () => {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    };
}, []);

  const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  
     if(nextAppState == 'active')
     {

         Clipboard.getString().then((content) => {
             if(content && content.length>0)
             {
                  
                 setPastContent(content)
             }

         }).catch(e=>{
             setError('incorrect code')
         })
     }

};
return <View>
<Text>{pastContent}</Text>
<TextInput value = {pastContent} ><TextInput>
</View>
}
```